# Deploy war generated on another job

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

I'm coding some integrations tests, and to run then I would like to first have jenkins running unit tests and quality scan in my code. On this first job the *war* would be generated.

After generating the *war* and sending statistics to SonarQube server I want to deploy the artifact generated on the first job to the test environment. I don't want to do this in the first job, because it is possible that the deploy process fails because of the test environment and if that happens the sonar statistics wouldn't be stored.

So I want to deploy the artifact generated in the first job to my tomcat on the test environment and trigger a third job to run the integration tests using the deployed *war*.

How can I configure jenkins to deploy an artifact generated during a previous job execution?

*I tried shared workspace, but couldn't figure out how to do it, and after a while I discovered it is a bad practice (because of files locked)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I managed to do it using the [Copy Artifact Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin), it allows a job to copy the artifact generated by other job